# Bubbling и capturing events javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему для отключения bubbling, необходимо это указывать в самом объекте события, а для - capturing- в event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда-то давно была "война браузеров", и взгляды на события в javascript у компании NetScape и Microsoft различались. NetScape использовали модель захвата, а MS всплытия. Соответственно были и разные методы для управления событиями. Когда началась стандартизация этого всего W3C в браузере должны были поддерживаться два вида событий: сначала захват и потом всплытие. Соответственно методы для управления первыми и управления вторыми не менялись и остались прежними, для обратной совместимости. Отсюда мы имеем два разных способа работы, но насколько я помню перехват событий захвата сейчас не используется и пользуются только перехватом на стадии всплытия.

Comment: интересно по какой причине bubbling стала де-факто стандартом ?

Comment: Micrisoft как всегда отличилась, IE и вплоть до 9 версии поддерживал только всплытие. Пока искал версию до который не было поддержки захвата, наткнулся на: [инновации IE](http://www.pvsm.ru/web-razrabotka/13605) и фраза оттуда: Internet Explorer до версии 9 поддерживал только всплывание событий. Хотя официальная спецификация События DOM постановила включить как захват событий, так и всплывание событий, большинство веб-разработчиков использует исключительно всплывание, тогда как захват событий остался для некоторых обходных путей и приёмов, спрятанных глубоко внутри javascript-библиотек.